# Make contents of compressed archive make target

Tags: makefile

Suppose I need to download a zipped archive containing thousands of compressed CSV files, and unzip it, and I want to use `make` for that process. The first step is easy:

```
myarchive.zip:
    curl -o myarchive.zip 'http://path/to/archive.zip'
```

But before downloading the archive, I don't know the name of every file in it. This doesn't work.

```
extracted/*.csv: myarchive.zip
    unzip myarchive.zip -d extracted
```

How do I let `make` know that all of these CSV files are targets?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you *want* the CSV files to be targets?

Comment: Not sure. I want to make sure that the archive is expanded into a directory that I can name, and rerun the process if it's not populated.

Comment: If you change the name of the second rule to something like `extract-archive`, that should give you everything you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. A more detailed example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want, but this is probably close:

```
ARCHIVE_DIR := extracted

.PHONY: archive
archive: myarchive.zip
    unzip $< -d $(ARCHIVE_DIR)

myarchive.zip:
    curl -o $@ 'http://path/to/archive.zip'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just needed to add `archive` to `all` and it works.

Comment: Make doesn't understand that the contents of `ARCHIVE_DIR` has not been updated though. But that's a minor issue.